# Product images imported through magmi

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, magmi

I have `Magento (CE1.9.2.4)` store with 30K products. I use `Magmi` to import products from a csv datafeed everyday. The product images are provided in more than one sizes (`200x200` to `2500x2500`) by my suppliers. Some of the products have multiple images/photos taken from different angles. I have been using the images with the best quality. But this causes a disk space problem.

I tried to find an image compressor / optimiser. I tested `jpegtran` but the compression has been less than 1% over 50K image files.

I have 2 questions:

1. 90% of my disk is full right now. I need to take a quick action. I'd like to import the images with less quality in order to free up some space on my servers disk. Those images have different URLs. What if I change the product image URLs (`image, small_image, thumbnail`) in my magmi import table?

   - is it going to overwrite the existing image files
   - or is it going to create new ones on the disk? What will happen to the previous product images? Do I need to delete them manually?
2. Do you have a different suggestion to compress those images?

Answer (score 2):

I would start by moving you image hosting to a CDN like AWS S3. If your webservers disk fills up with images this could affect the availability and performance of your shop.
Never used it but [this module](https://github.com/mVentory/MVentory_S3CDN) looks like a good option.

If you're hosting on Linux try **jpgoptim**, I use it as a cronjob daily to find all images modified that day and compress them. Works quite well but in the end compression will only get you so far, it only trashes some unused meta data and reduces on the image information but if you download 4 megapixel images it will still cost you a lot of space.

An option for that would be to [use **imagick** to resize the actual size](http://www.howtogeek.com/109369/how-to-quickly-resize-convert-modify-images-from-the-linux-terminal/) of the images. Depending on the kind of shop you might not need large, detailed images.

Regarding question 1.
I'm no Magmi expert, actually never use it, but it probably uses the image name (so without remote path) to store the image. If the images have the same name it will rewrite, otherwise it will just create new local files.

Comment: Also might be worth to check out [Rapido](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/rapido-image-optimizer-1.html) in the short term. Full disclosure: I know the guys behind this and try to have beer with them in Amsterdam whenever I visit.

Comment: @j-corby yup, Rapido is quite cool and built by some really good Magento developers

Comment: I'll try **jpgoptim** as well. I am looking for free solution at the moment. I may use rapido later. Thanks for all the suggestions!

Comment: @J.Corby : Could you pls guide me how can you import products images using magmi

Comment: @Jeeva I don't know if you already use Magmi or not. You just need to have the 'image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail' fields in your CSV file. I import images from a remote location. I use the same image url for image, small_image and thumbnail fields. Please check http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Image_attributes_processor.